# How to enable request metrics for S3 bucket using Cloudformation or CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am able to enable (request metrics for S3 bucket, apid option) in the AWS console manually by checking the checkbox(https://ibb.co/bWDLcNT). But I am trying to do that via code. I tried finding solutions that uses CloudFormation / CDK(nodeJs) / AWS CLI. But no luck. I found solutions only about creating metrics with the filters etc and not much about enabling it.. Any suggestions?

Comment: ". But no luck. " - can you provide some CFN template that you try and why it fails (error messages?).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I tried finding solutions". I corrected that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [MetricsConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-metricsconfiguration.html):

> Specifies a metrics configuration for the CloudWatch **request metrics** (specified by the metrics configuration ID) from an Amazon S3 bucket.

The example would be:

```
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: somey-bucket-3344-name
      MetricsConfigurations: 
        - Id: EntireBucket
```

Note **EntireBucket**. This is the **required** Id to enable the paid metrics.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have spent several hours looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

The [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) equivalent for Marcin's answer would be to use the [Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html) construct:

```
new Bucket(this, 'metric-example-bucket', {
  bucketName: "somey-bucket-3344-name",
  metrics: [{
    id: "EntireBucket"
  }]
})
```

If you've already created that bucket in CDK, you can use the [addMetric()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#add-wbr-metricmetric) method:

```
existingBucket.addMetric({id: "EntireBucket"})
```